# Fatorar numeros de 1 a 9, variável acumuladora imprimindo número errado

Tags: lua

Por que a minha variável acumuladora não imprime 6?

```
acum=1
n1=6
for i=1,2,3 do
    if n1%2==0 then acum=acum*2 n1=n1/2  
        elseif  n1%3==0 then acum=acum*3 n1=n1/3
            elseif  n1%5==0 then acum=acum*5 n1=n1/5
                elseif n1%7==0 then acum=acum*7 n1=n1/7 
    end
    if n1==1 then break end
end

print(acum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vou mexer muito na estrutura do código, mas vou escrever de forma que fique legível e em estilo mais correto. O problema mesmo é o `for`. Os números colocados ali parecem ser aleatórios. O primeiro deve ser o início do laço, então 1 está correto. O segundo indica o fim do laço, então deveria ser 9 e não 2. O terceiro é de quanto em quanto ele deve pular em cada passagem pelo laço, então deveria ser 1. Assim:

```
local acum = 1
local n1 = 6
for i = 1, 9, 1 do
    if n1 % 2 == 0 then
        acum = acum * 2
        n1 = n1 / 2
    elseif n1 % 3 == 0 then
        acum = acum * 3
        n1 = n1 / 3
    elseif n1 % 5 == 0 then
        acum = acum * 5
        n1 = n1 / 5
    elseif n1 % 7 == 0 then
        acum = acum * 7
        n1 = n1 / 7 
    end
    if n1 == 1 then break end
end
print(acum)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IwNkwU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uttojbbn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Accumulate.lua).